# rails check_box failing on boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a postgres db with a bool field `:on_farm_tour`. But I'm getting this in the view:

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<Class:0x10ddec5c0>
Extracted source (around line #10):

7: 
8: %p
9:   =f.label :on_farm_tour, "This farm is in the Farm Tour?"
10:   =f.check_box :on_farm_tour
11: 
12: %p
13:   =f.label :last_mile_directions, 'Enter driving directions from the last point displayed by Google Maps for this farm to the actual location of the farm'
```

Obviously I know that `true.to_i` is undefined, but what is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Can we take a look at the beginning of the form, i.e. the 6 first lines?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a gotcha issue. Try to use check_box_tag instead. Take a look at what [apidock.com](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) says about it:

> Gotcha
>
> The HTML specification says unchecked
>   check boxes are not successful, and
>   thus web browsers do not send them.
>   Unfortunately this introduces a
>   gotcha: if an Invoice model has a paid
>   flag, and in the form that edits a
>   paid invoice the user unchecks its
>   check box, no paid parameter is sent.
>   So, any mass-assignment idiom like
>
> ```
> @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice])
> ```
>
> wouldn’t update the flag.
>
> To prevent this the helper generates
>   an auxiliary hidden field before the
>   very check box. The hidden field has
>   the same name and its attributes mimic
>   an unchecked check box.
>
> This way, the client either sends only
>   the hidden field (representing the
>   check box is unchecked), or both
>   fields. Since the HTML specification
>   says key/value pairs have to be sent
>   in the same order they appear in the
>   form, and parameters extraction gets
>   the last occurrence of any repeated
>   key in the query string, that works
>   for ordinary forms.
>
> Unfortunately that workaround does not
>   work when the check box goes within an
>   array-like parameter, as in
>
> ```
> <%= fields_for "project[invoice_attributes][]",
> ```
>
> invoice, :index => nil do |form| %>
>         <%= form.check_box :paid %>
>         ...
>       <% end %>
>
> because parameter name repetition is
>   precisely what Rails seeks to
>   distinguish the elements of the array.
>   For each item with a checked check box
>   you get an extra ghost item with only
>   that attribute, assigned to "0".
>
> In that case it is preferable to
>   either use check_box_tag or to use
>   hashes instead of arrays.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. The checkbox never renders because the code chokes. It seems to be a rails version issue. Just upgraded an old project to 2.3.11 from 2.3.4 and that seems to solve the issue.